# Need Help in This Approval Process?

Tags: approval-process

If Loan amount approval as below :

- If Loan amount is < 100K ------ it should auto approve
- If loan amount is < 1000k --- It should have manager approval
- If loan amount is >2000K ---- It should have two levels of approvals

  1. Manager approval
  2. Regional Manager approval

How to Set for Auto Approval and two level approval?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This site exists to *help* you, not do work for you. From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."* Please read more Help Center & also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). Then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/360987/edit) your question to add what you have tried (e.g., code, screenshots of approval process steps) & how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first go through the approval process unit to know the basics of `approval process`. It's not a complicate one to understand.

So please refer this `Approval process` trailhead,

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-discount-approval-process

Which will provide you some knowledge then you can able to do that in yourself.

Thanks.